# How to programmatically set the size of the font in the list item before adding it to the ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview, text-size

I'm interested in how you can change the size of the text in the list and then add it to the ListView. I'm using a list_item with custom layout . The question is how you can set the size of the text before it gets into the ListView. I hope for your help.

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shop_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shop_address"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2"
        />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**day_list_events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    >

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/day_and_data"
    android:text="Перелік клієнтів на сьогоднішній день."
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/help_info"
    android:text="(Щоб отримати інформацію про клієнта та оформити замовлення - натисніть на відповідного клієнта у списку)"
    android:textColor="#A0A0A0"
    />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/day_list_event"
    >

</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**DayListEventsActivity.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class DayListEventsActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.day_list_events);
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("impInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Resources res = this.getResources();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dayShopsInfo = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    String[] shopName = res.getStringArray(R.array.shop_name);
    String[] shopAddress = res.getStringArray(R.array.shop_address);        
    for(int i = 0; i < shopName.length; i++){
        HashMap<String, String> dayShopsInfoCont = new HashMap<String, String>();
        dayShopsInfoCont.put(KEY_SHOP_NAME, shopName[i]);
        dayShopsInfoCont.put(KEY_SHOP_ADDRESS, shopAddress[i]);
        System.out.println(i+" "+shopName[i]+" "+shopAddress[i]);
        dayShopsInfo.add(dayShopsInfoCont);         
    }
    ListView shopList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.day_list_event);
    SimpleAdapter shopListAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,
            dayShopsInfo,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[]{KEY_SHOP_NAME, KEY_SHOP_ADDRESS},
            new int[]{R.id.shop_name, R.id.shop_address});
    shopList.setAdapter(shopListAdapter);
    shopList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
}

private final String KEY_SHOP_NAME = "shop name";
private final String KEY_SHOP_ADDRESS = "shop address";
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
}
```

**UPDATE (Solution).**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DayListEventsActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.day_list_events);
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("impInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Resources res = this.getResources();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dayShopsInfo = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    String[] shopName = res.getStringArray(R.array.shop_name);
    String[] shopAddress = res.getStringArray(R.array.shop_address);        
    for(int i = 0; i < shopName.length; i++){
        HashMap<String, String> dayShopsInfoCont = new HashMap<String, String>();
        dayShopsInfoCont.put(KEY_SHOP_NAME, shopName[i]);
        dayShopsInfoCont.put(KEY_SHOP_ADDRESS, shopAddress[i]);
        System.out.println(i+" "+shopName[i]+" "+shopAddress[i]);
        dayShopsInfo.add(dayShopsInfoCont);         
    }
    ListView shopList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.day_list_event);
    MySimpleAdapter shopListAdapter = new MySimpleAdapter(this,
            dayShopsInfo,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[]{KEY_SHOP_NAME, KEY_SHOP_ADDRESS},
            new int[]{R.id.shop_name, R.id.shop_address});
    shopList.setAdapter(shopListAdapter);
    shopList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
}

public class MySimpleAdapter extends SimpleAdapter{

    public MySimpleAdapter(Context context,
                            List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data,
                            int resource,
                            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);           
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View returnView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView shopName = (TextView)returnView.findViewById(R.id.shop_name);
        shopName.setTextSize(20.0f);
        return returnView;
    }

}

private final String KEY_SHOP_NAME = "shop name";
private final String KEY_SHOP_ADDRESS = "shop address";
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply do this in the `getView()` method of the `Adapter`, to set the `font` size.

`tv.setTextSize(20.0f);`

Comment: That is, I need to create your own Adapter - inherit a version of a standard adapter and override getView()?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using xml for setting layout for `list_item` and there you have `TextView` you can change the size of the text like this:

```
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/text_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textSize="20sp" /> // This is a size of your text
```

Comment: ))) Does not depend on the size of the test should he screen resolution - so I had to change it programmatically

Answer (score 1):

There's not "size of text"
You can change the size of the text  inside the TextView:
Add:

```
 android:textSize="16sp"
```

TO your XML
Or you can do it by code in the getView() method in the Adapter:

```
YOUR_TEXTVIEW.setTextSize(16);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be a little late, however I noticed that everyone forgot something in their answers. the method setTextSize takes 2 parameters for it's input. The second if a float that is the number of the size you want. The first is a TypedValue Constant to let specify what the number means ie: pixels, dip, sp, etc... so for the setTextSize set to 18sp it would look something like this:

```
TextView yourTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId);
yourTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,18)
```

and you would do it in the getView of the ArrayAdapter. Hope this helps someone else who was looking for an answer and stumble upon this one.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.yourTextViewId);
textView.setTextSize(18);
```

Comment: Sorry - but that does not work - because the adapter you need to pass the id, not the objects.